# How to pass an argument as a new command's name?

Tags: macros

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\DefineRealCommand}[1]
{
    {The real command name is: #1}
    \newcommand*{\#1}{I am the real command.}
}

\DefineRealCommand{HelloCommand}

\begin{document}
\HelloCommand
\end{document}
```

My purpose is obvious. However, the simplest tex file cannot be compiled.

How should I implement it correctly?

Comment: Surely a duplicate, but: `\newcommand\cmdmaker[2]{\expandafter\newcommand\csname #1\endcsname{\textbf{#2}}}` Set the command: `\cmdmaker{firstone}{Looks like this}` `\cmdmaker{secondone}{Looks rather like firstone}`. Use the command in the document: `\firstone \par \secondone`.